# Non-standard configuration names in C++ projects break NuGet linking

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I wanted to use two configurations in my Visual Studio 2019 C++ project, lets say I wanted to rename `Debug` to `Debug-A` and add a new configuration called `Debug-B` based on `Debug-A`.
`Debug-A` and `Debug-B` differ only by one define symbol, lets say one has `SYMBOL_A` and another has `SYMBOL_B`.

Currently, I don't care about Release and anything other than x64.

[image: Configuration manager]

It works corretly until I add a NuGet package (for example fmt). Then, when I try to compile, I get undefined symbol linker errors. Just like `fmtd.lib` was not included, if I include it manually (or change the project configuration name to `Debug`), the issue is gone.

I know the reason why NuGet includes it if my project configuration is named `Debug`. Look at the nuget package targets file (`packages/fmt.7.0.1/build/fmt.targets`) - lib files are hardcoded to `$(Configuration)` being either `Debug` or `Release`.
As far as I know, all NuGet C++ packages are built this way.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <!-- ... -->
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">
    <Link>
      <AdditionalDependencies>fmtd.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
    </Link>
    <Lib>
      <AdditionalDependencies>fmtd.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
    </Lib>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">
    <Link>
      <AdditionalDependencies>fmt.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
    </Link>
   <Lib>
      <AdditionalDependencies>fmt.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
    </Lib>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <!-- ... -->
</Project>
```

I know I can manually link the libs, but fmt was just an example, I use a lot of packages and manually linking will become an issue quite fast.

Is there any way to use the quick selection of preprocessor symbols provided by active solution configuration (the toolbar dropdown) and still be able to use NuGet properly? For example parsing the nuget files with fake `$(Configuration)` variable. Using `$(Platform)` (`x86`, `x64` etc.) is impossible, library include path is depending on it's hardcoded value too.

[Sample project with this bug](https://gist.github.com/chanibal/5056595fb87698dcae9b2c8fc3a441e0/).

Answer (score 1):

If, as you mentioned, the NuGet Packages’ lib files are hardcoded, then we may need to find solutions from other sides, for example `.vcxproj` file or MSBuild.

I didn’t find any directly properties/parameters/ways which meet your requirements. But, is it possible to keep the `Debug` name, I mean, leave it named `Debug` not `Debug-A` or `Debug-B`, and then switch to use different Configurations by using other methods. Imagine there is a Debug configuration file(DebugB)(maybe DebugB related things are set in this file) excluded in the project and the project currently use another Debug configuration(DebugA), and during the build, the project will exactly use DebugA configuration. To switch, do something, or add a code line in `.vcxproj` file to include the file which contains DebugB configuration, and then let the DebugB configuration cover the DebugA configuration.

So, for covering the properties/items of `.vcproj` file. Perhaps [customize build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019#customize-c-builds) works.

Hope above could give you a little help.